# How to make arbitrary code blocks foldable in spyder

Tags: spyder

I want to group arbitrary blocks of code, say parts of a script. And then I want to be able to collapse them, just like I can collapse classes, function definitions and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in Spyder 4 or later by defining a code block with a comment like so:

```
# %% lines below here can be collapsed
```